# Pass parameter to Angular 7 template driven form custom validator

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-template-form

How can I pass a parameter to a custom validator written for a Template Driven Form in Angular 7?

I've got the following code put together from multiple other questions and blog posts, but most center around Reactive forms rather than tempalte.

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn, NG_VALIDATORS, Validator, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

// validation function
function validateMinValue(minValue: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl) => {

        console.log(minValue); 
        return null;
    }
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[minValue][ngModel]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: MinValueValidator, multi: true }
    ]
})
export class MinValueValidator implements Validator {
    @Input("minValue") minValue;
    validator: ValidatorFn;

    constructor() {
        this.validator = validateMinValue(this.minValue);
    }

    validate(c: FormControl) {
        return this.validator(c);
    }
}
```

How could I access the value passed to minValue in an input like this

```
<input type="text" name="testInput" class="form-control"
        [(ngModel)]="testValue" required
        currencyMask [options]="{ thousands: ',', decimal: '.' }"
        minValue="100">
```

Comment: [Through directives only](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-to-template-driven-forms)

Comment: Have you tried to use ngOnInit instead of constructor to initialize validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `ngOnInit` hook to initialize validator since there is no Input property initialized in constructor yet.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.validator = validateMinValue(this.minValue);
}
```

This way the initialized value will be passed to your validator.

Another way is to simple define validator within your custom directive and take `minValue` from current context `this`:

```
export class MinValueValidator implements Validator {
    @Input("minValue") minValue;

    validate(c: FormControl) {
        console.log(this.minValue); 
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: While true, it doesn't answer the question about *how* to pass the parameter to the validator

Comment: @Maryannah, OP is doing the right thing, now it's successfully passed when moving code into `OnInit` like in answer :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ur8ju?file=src/app/app.component.html And to the OP: notice that you need to use `[minValue]="100"` if you want to pass a number, which I assume you want.